# where does inflectors go using ember rails

Tags: ember-rails

ember version:  * @version   1.4.0
ember-data Version: v0.14

In my store.js

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    namespace: "api/v1"
});

Lost.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 14,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter
});
```

Works fine for me. when i route into properties. my RESTAdapter calls

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/propertys
```

so far so good. except i just need to use ember inflectors to change the "propertys" in call to "properties"

**case1:**
In my store.js after the above mentioned code

```
var inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector;
inflector.irregular('property', 'properties');
```

gives error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inflector' of undefined
```

**case 2**
In my store.js after the above mentioned code

```
var inflector = new Ember.Inflector();
inflector.irregular('property', 'properties');
```

gives error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**case 3**
but when i put it before my Lost.Store

I get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inflector' of undefined application.js:65532
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You included Ember Data but didn't define Lost.Store
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Ember Data version 0.14 has Ember.Inflector. Have you tried upgrading to Ember Data version 1.0.0.beta.6ish.